# When to use が and when to use は

Tags: grammar, particle-は, particle-が

I am a little confused when speaking Japanese when I should use が and when I should use は. For example, 学校はたのしかったです。or 学校がたのしかったです。What is the rule of when to use が and when to use は in a context?

Comment: This question is so simple yet so hard to answer. Have you looked at the other questions on は and が on this site?　Try starting with this one http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/22/whats-the-difference-between-wa-%E3%81%AF-and-ga-%E3%81%8C?rq=1

Comment: You sound like a beginner. My advice is: use は unless you have a reason to use が. Good reasons to use が include relative clauses and question words (e.g. 何が、誰が)

Comment: @user3856370 Thanks for the edit. I didn't realise that I had put わ instead of は.I have looked at a few similar questions, but I cannot find a definitive rule on this subject.

Comment: @oals Actually, I am semi-fluent at Japanese, got an A in my GCSE Japanese and lived there for 6 years. But my main weakness is grammar as I haven't learned that properly

Comment: @user3856370 That link does answer my question. Thanks for the help!